# Best way to filter an XML into ILookup and search there after

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I am pretty new to .Net LINQ can anyone suggest a best and smart way to filter this xml into .Net object, so in the code I can easily execute required testcases for a testsuite

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TestSuites>
  <TestSuite name="TS1" canexecute ="true">
    <TestCase name="TC1" canexecute ="true"/>
    <TestCase name="TC2" canexecute ="false"/>
    <TestCase name="TC3" canexecute ="true"/>
  </TestSuite>
  <TestSuite name="TS2" canexecute ="false">
    <TestCase name="TC4" canexecute ="true"/>
    <TestCase name="TC5" canexecute ="false"/>
    <TestCase name="TC6" canexecute ="true"/>
  </TestSuite>
  <TestSuite name="TS3" canexecute ="false">
    <TestCase name="TC7" canexecute ="true"/>
    <TestCase name="TC8" canexecute ="false"/>
    <TestCase name="TC9" canexecute ="true"/>
  </TestSuite>
</TestSuites>

Expected output
Key   Value
TS1   TC1
      TC3
TS3   TC7
      TC9
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you want something like:

```
var query = doc.Descendants("TestSuite")
               .Where(x => (bool) x.Attribute("canexecute"))
               .Elements("TestCase")
               .Where(x => (bool) x.Attribute("canexecute"))
               .ToLookup(x => (string) x.Parent.Attribute("name"),
                         x => (string) x.Attribute("name"));
```

So that says:

- Find all the test suites...
- ... which can execute
- ... then find their test cases...
- ... which can execute
- ... then group by the test suite name, with the values in the group being the test case name

Note that with the above query if you have multiple test suites with the same name, they'll be flattened to a single group.

Comment: Secondly, from the ILookup<string,string> lookUp is there a direct way to find if the key exists (eg: LookUp.Key.Contains("TS1"))
Should I have to expicitly loop in knowing if TC1 exists in TS1. quick sample code could certainly help. thankx again John.

Comment: @user2271512 `ILookup` interfaces declares [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548655.aspx) method which checks if key exists in lookup, so you can simply call `LookUp.Contain("TS1")`.